# Is it possible to know if the client (browser) is running on the same machine as the server?

Tags: java, http, servlets

I have a server-side application written in Java.

We use Jetty to provide our servlets.

Final users use the browser to 'use' our app.

From a server-side point of view when I get an `HttpServletRequest` is it possible to know if it from a browser which is running on the same machine that the server has been installed on?

(that being the case I am obviously testing and I would like to do something about it)

Comment: Short answer: yes, it is possible. Use [`ServletRequest#getRemoteAddr()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr()). It should return something like `127.0.0.1` (IPv4) or `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` (IPv6) when testing from your own pc.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: using `InetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()` would help with detecting IPv6 Loopback addresses as well (which can easily happen) and also with all the other loopback addresses (127.0.0.2, ...)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: This should be an answer.

Comment: I don't see why you would need to know. What difference should it make?

Comment: @EJP if the browser is running locally a few diagnostic pages will be available.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza thanks your comments were valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can check whether the ip address of the request is the same as server's or if it's coming from localhost?

I guess this can help:

```
String getRemoteIP(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String xff = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
    if (xff != null) {
        return xff.split("[\\s,]+")[0];
    }
    return request.getRemoteAddr();
}
```

Compare this address to server's.

I took this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018113/how-to-get-the-subnet-ip-adress-from-http-request)

Comment: In its current form this should be a comment (since you can't answer a question with another question (: ). Please update it to look like an answer or delete it and post a comment instead.

Comment: Next time **explicitly** show where you get the code. Obviously it wasn't from the top of your head: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2018153/1065197.

Comment: Note that the `X-Forwarded-For` header can easily be faked, and in this case you probably *don't* want to inspect it at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ServletRequest.getRemoteHost()` which returns  the fully qualified name of the client that sent the request and compare it to local host name `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName()`